# Leafletjs: how to access and update a marker inside a layer

Tags: javascript, leaflet, layer, markers

I have a list with different locations. Everytime someone clicks on a location I remove the marker layer from my map and then a function is triggered which makes a new layer of markers with the same locations as before, only this time is uses a different icon for the selected location.

My problem is that I don't want to remove and add the layer, instead I just want to update the icon of the specific marker but I cannot find a way to access it.

Someone mentioned that this is possible through .eachLayer function but I cannot see how, since this one is to control the layers, not the markers.

```
markers = new L.featureGroup(); 


function updateMarker(locations, clickedID){
    //Adding all markers on map
    for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) 
    {       
        //red marker for the selected location
        if (locations[i][2] == clickedID){
            marker = new L.marker([locations[i][0],locations[i][1]],{
                icon: redIcon})
                .bindPopup(locations[i][3]);
            markers.addLayer(marker);   
        }
        else{
            //add regular marker
            marker = new L.marker([locations[i][0],locations[i][1]])
                .bindPopup(locations[i][3])
                .addTo(map);
            markers.addLayer(marker);
        }


    } ;

    map.addLayer(markers);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without an example, what you want to achieve is not 100% clear.

However, if you want to manipulate markers (using setIcon() for example), it is much easier to keep an array of all your markers.

```
var markers = {};   // list of created markers
```

When you create a marker, you add it to your array

```
markers[theID] = L.marker();
map.addLayer(markers[theID]);
```

You can then modify your marker easily without having to scan your featureGroup.

```
markers[theID].setIcon();
```

Comment: So I will have to use a list instead of the leafletjs layer and add each marker on the map seperately, am I right?
If setIcon() updates the icon of the marker instantly I think it'll do the work. Thank you.

Comment: Definitely working. Thank you. :)  Maybe you know if there is an easy way to get back the default icon, or do I have to create a new custom one with the blue icon?

Comment: you can use L.Icon.Default: http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.0.html#icon-default-imagepath

Comment: Forgive my ignorance, but can you elaborate on `[theID]` is? I'm very new to working with leaflet and arrays in general.

Comment: theID is a unique id (you will create one per marker) that will be used to retrieve the marker from the array when you need it. For example take a look at http://franceimage.github.io/map/ (array is created from this file https://github.com/franceimage/franceimage.github.io/blob/master/map/data/franceimage-markerlist.json)